# To find those values in column whose values are near by to 10,20,30...so on through sql query

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

I have a sql query which retrieves values from three tables .Whenever certain column value is 0 then the corresponding column value will be displayed otherwise 0 will be entered in that column.Now **`I want to retrieve only those values from beam_current where values are near by to 10,20,30,40 ..till 220`** .My current sql query is:-

```
select b.LOGTIME, b.beam_current, b.beam_energy,
  case when a.st1_vs1_bag1_onoff=0 and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag1_rb ELSE 0 END as st1_vs1_bag1_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag2_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag2_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag2_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag3_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag3_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag3_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag4_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag4_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag4_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag5_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag5_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag5_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag6_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag6_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag6_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag7_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag7_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag7_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag8_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag8_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag8_rb 

 from INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT b  INNER JOIN (main_vacuum_analog c inner join main_vacuum_status a on c.logtime=a.logtime) ON a.LOGTIME = b.LOGTIME 
--and (b.beam_current between 4.99 and 5.01
--or b.beam_current in (9.99, 10.00,10.01))
and b.logtime between '2014-10-10 07:17:00' and '2014-10-10 08:46:00'
```

**`EDIT 1`**

**The Case statement will check if there is any st1_vs1_bag2_onoff=0 then it will show the value of st1_vs1_bag2_rb otherwise 0 will be displayed at the corresponding values** **and we also retrieve all the beam_current values but i want only those values in beam_current which are nearby to 10,20,30...till 220**.**`Is there any way to specify such a near by condition in sql query in sql server2012`**

Comment: st1_vs1_bag1_onoff is equated to 0 as well as '0'. I think you should elaborate your existing relation and the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing, that "nearby" means "values of `beam_current` that are close to 10, 20, 30, ..., 220."

How close? the following formula gives you NN +- 0.01. `%` is [Modulo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx)

```
and (b.beam_current % 10.0 <= 0.01 OR b.beam_current % 10.0 >= 9.99)
and (b.beam_current >= 9.99) -- to set the lower limit of 9.99
and (b.beam_current <= 220.01) -- to set the upper limit of 220.01
```

Add these into the `WHERE` clause of your `SELECT`.

**Edit:**

Now that we know that `beam_current` is of `real` type we can simply convert `real` type to [`numeric`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187746.aspx):

```
and (CAST(b.beam_current as numeric(9,2)) % 10.0 <= 0.01 
    OR 
    CAST(b.beam_current as numeric(9,2)) % 10.0 >= 9.99)
and (b.beam_current >= 9.99) -- to set the lower limit of 9.99
and (b.beam_current <= 220.01) -- to set the upper limit of 220.01
```

In this case precision 9 should be enough, because the values are less than 220.01 and we are interested only in two decimal places.

Comment: my beam_current values are of real type and close means any near by value to 10,20...

Comment: The data types real and numeric are incompatible in the modulo operator, this error message comes as beam_current is of real type

Comment: @SRY_JAVA, just add conversion to `numeric` type. See the edited post

Comment: is there any way in sql query where I can find only a single row corresponding to the most  nearby values to 10,20 ,30.As through this method , my getting values of beam_current from 9.95 to 210 but I want only the most near by values.Is there any way to find just the single row corrsponding to neraby values??

Comment: @SRY_JAVA, this is a quite different question and the query would be significantly different. You'd better ask a new question and clearly explain what you need, provide a sample of your data without irrelevant details and provide expected result of the query. If you do it like this the chances that you'll get a good answer would be much higher.